# Connect to Oracle Database from MS Excel or Power BI

Tags: excel, oracle, data-connections

Trying to access tables from Oracle using MS Excel 2019, yet every time I tried to access the oracle from the Data ribbon /Get Data, a pop message got displayed stating:
``

## The recommended provider ('Oracle.DataAccess.Client') is not installed,...#

``
the message has a Learn More link which advice to install Oracle Client for Micorsoft tool to resolve.

I apprecaite your help to resolve this.

I did  install the tool after download the tool for Windows 64 from this Oracle web site https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/ocmt.html.

Yet this didn't resolve the issue, and still the popup message getting displayed.

Comment: is your office 32 bit or 62 bit?

Comment: Windows 10  is  64bit and MS Office is 2019 not Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

If there are still problems accessing Oracle data after installing Oracle Client for Microsoft, I suggest using Devart ODBC. I have encountered the same problem and solved it with Devart ODBC. Later, I found that using the [Devart ODBC driver](https://www.devart.com/odbc/Oracle/) can bypass the problems faced by Oracle clients and establish a direct connection to the Oracle database, so that you can access the tables in the database. I also tested standard functions and data types. There is no problem.